# Magento 2, custom cms layout, override general removal of a block

Tags: magento2, page-layouts, breadcrumbs

In my `/app/design/frontend/myVendor/myTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`
I have below :

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
```

And in my custom layout for a specefic page I need to have it. So in my

```
app/design/frontend/myVendor/myTheme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/myCustomPage-layout.xml
```

I added below:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

But can not get the breadcrumb display.

Comment: try this link  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131946/magento-2-breadcrumbs-copy
or
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104815/magento-2-call-breadcrumbs-on-category-product-pages

Comment: But I do not have a specific phtml file. I'm using cms page

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the name of the block. So you need to change

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

to

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="custom_breadcrumbs" as="custom_breadcrumbs"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: I did not change the breadcrumbs's block name. But I tried your code and still not displaying the breadcrumbs :(

Comment: Have you cleared the cache after done the changes in your layout xml file?

Comment: Yeap, I did that... wondering why it does not, as your code sounds promising...I guess I have to go with css :(